# Method never returns when thread join

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading

I'm creating an Android application where I've a login system using MySql. I'm using a Thread for the login.

```
private static boolean isValid = false;
public static boolean login(final String username, final String password) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://*****/***","*****","******");
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT passHash FROM test WHERE username = '"+ username +"'";
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println(query + " <----");

                while(rs.next()) {
                    isValid = BCrypt.checkpw(password, rs.getString(1));

                    System.out.println(isValid + "<.daspdfsafpa");
                }
                System.out.println(isValid +" 1");
                con.close();
                System.out.println(isValid +" 2");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    try{
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("blafasf");
    return isValid;
}
```

When I'm using the `Thread.currentThread.join();` the app never runs the `return isValid;.` So my method will never get returned when I'm using the `.join()` , and if I remove it the method will be returned before the thread is done. How can I fix this issue?

**I want the method to run through the thread before returning the `isValid` in the bottom of the method.**

Any ideas?

I'm still looking for a solution on this. How can I make this is another way to still make it work?

Comment: You need to use a ref to the thread which executes the query and login validation and call .join() on that one. Btw, why are you nesting Runnable into Thread?

Comment: @marekful So, something like Thread th = new Thread();? 

Using the Runnable is the only way I can find this one working. Otherwise I'm getting an error from the MySQL.

Comment: Yes, and then when `th.join()` is executed, it will cause the main thread to wait until `th` terminates.

Comment: @marekful Can't make the MySQL to work that way... I'll do a test and send you. Hold on.

Comment: @marekful `** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
    java.net.SocketException
    MESSAGE: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    STACKTRACE:` I'm getting this error when doing that way..

Check my temp edit